# Vectorizing a Conditional Update Operation in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, vectorization

My first question here!  I'm looking for help on how to vectorize an operation on a pandas dataframe.  I can simplify the problem down to a dataframe with three columns, a column that has values that will be updated, and two columns that have an iteration number, which is not the same between the two columns.

What I'd like to do is for one of the iteration columns, for each of the first values in the iteration column, to then refer to the corresponding value of the other iteration column (at that same index), and then finally to fill a value (zero) to the column with update values, but only for the rows in which the second iteration column has that same value.  Hopefully this example will explain a bit better:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['update_col'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df['iter2'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
df['iter1'] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

print(df)
#     update_col    iter2     iter1
0              1        0         0
1              2        1         0
2              3        1         1
3              4        2         1
4              5        2         1
5              6        3         2
6              7        3         2
7              8        4         2
8              9        4         2
```

So basically, I want to do the following:

1. Reference the iter1 column, and when it changes (i.e. goes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 2)
2. Look at the iter2 column at that index
3. Change the values in the "update column" to zero for all rows starting from the index in step 2 until iter2 is incremented to a new value

So the output would look like the following:

```
#     update_col    iter2     iter1
0              1        0         0
1              2        1         0
2              0        1         1
3              4        2         1
4              5        2         1
5              0        3         2
6              0        3         2
7              8        4         2
8              9        4         2
```

I think a properly constructed `groupby` could be a solution, but I am still a rookie at using it effectively.

I am currently achieving what I want with a complicated for loop, it makes the run time extremely long for the size and number of dataframes that I have to do this to.  I think another solution could be a `map` or `replace` operation, but the complicating caveat is that I don't want to update all of the values for that value of iter2, only the values from that index of iter 1 until the last of those values in iter2.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: just to clarify, are you looking to perform this sequence:

(1) iter1 is incremented, then (2) if iter2 == iter1, set update_col to 0 ?

Not sure I understand the caveat at the end. If you're looking to clean up the looping code, have you considered using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: So, I don't care whether or not iter2 == iter1.  If iter1 is incremented, that is the trigger to step over to iter2 (at that index), get its value (whatever it is), and then assign 0 to update_col from that index until the value of iter2 is incremented.  Hope this helps bring clarity.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit clearer...I think it might help to use a slightly modified dataframe in your example, maybe one that shows this propagation a little more clearly (where you're setting multiple consecutive rows to `0`)? If I'm I understanding correctly, you keep setting successive values of `update_col` to `0` until you hit the next `iter2` increment. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking to do.  I updated the df in the example to try and more clearly illustrate that.

Comment: great! much clearer in the new example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a huge improvement on the loop you already have defined, but I think it eliminates the need to use a nested loop at least:

```
import pandas as pd

# creating data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['update_col'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df['iter2'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
df['iter1'] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

# computing difference from prev element by creating a shifted col 
# and subtracting from the original.
# (you could also use a rolling window function for this)
df['change1'] = df['iter1'] - df['iter1'].shift(1)
df['change2'] = df['iter2'] - df['iter2'].shift(1)

# creating boolean cols to flag if iter1 or iter2 have changed
df['start'] = df['change1'] == 1
df['stop'] = df['change2'] == 1

# list to store result: if True, you update value to 0
res = [False] * len(df['start'])

for i in range(0, len(df['start'])):
    if df['start'][i]:
        #print('start detected')
        res[i] = True
    elif i > 1 and (not df['stop'][i]) and res[i-1]: 
        #print('continuation detected')
        res[i] = True
    #print(f'set res[{i}] to ', res[i])

df['update_to_zero'] = res
```

Which results in this df:

```
   update_col  iter2  iter1  change1  change2  start   stop  update_to_zero
0           1      0      0      NaN      NaN  False  False           False
1           2      1      0      0.0      1.0  False   True           False
2           3      1      1      1.0      0.0   True  False            True
3           4      2      1      0.0      1.0  False   True           False
4           5      2      1      0.0      0.0  False  False           False
5           6      3      2      1.0      1.0   True   True            True
6           7      3      2      0.0      0.0  False  False            True
7           8      4      2      0.0      1.0  False   True           False
8           9      4      2      0.0      0.0  False  False           False
```

Hope this helps!